# sendmail() php xampp localhost Rede com proxy

Tags: php

Galera, eu enviava normalmente email LOCALHOST utilizando o sendmail

```
mail($to, $assuntoHTML, $mensagemHTML, $headers) 

[sendmail]

 smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port=587
 error_logfile=error.log
 debug_logfile=debug.log
 smtp_ssl=auto
 auth_username=meuemail@gmail.com
 auth_password=minhasenha

 smtp_ssl=tls
 tls_certcheck off
```

Acontece que na rede do trabalho, colocaram um proxy.

Eu fui lá e abri a porta smtp 587, mas mesmo assim nao consigo enviar mais email

Alguém pode me ajudar a , talvez, inserir a informação do proxy pra ver se dá certo ?

Tipo use proxy 192.1.1.1 port 1234

Muito obrigado.

php.ini

```
[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = meuemail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\"\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

Answer (score 1):

A julgar pelas opções adicionais não presentes por padrão no PHP.INI eu diria que você está usando o [Fake Sendmail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) para Windows, correto?

Assumindo que sim, conforme parte de [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6292400/753531) no SOEN a respeito do PHP-Mailer, não existe isso de proxy SMTP, basta que você defina o host e a porta de origem o que, no Fake Sendmail, aparenta ser feito configurando a diretiva **hostname** no arquivo **sendmail.ini**:

```
hostname=192.1.1.1:1234
```

Lembre-se de reiniciar o servidor depois de salvar o arquivo de configuração.

Comment: Não estou utilizando fake, meu php.ini está assim:
    [mail function]
    SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port = 587
    sendmail_from = meuemail@gmail.com
    sendmail_path = "C:\"\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
    mail.add_x_header = Off

Comment: No diretório onde seu XAMPP foi instalado verifique se existe um subdiretório **sendmail** e se nele há um arquivo **sendmail.ini**. Se não houver, experimente adicionar a diretiva **hostname** diretamente no PHP.INI em qualquer parte dentro da seção `[sendmail]`

Comment: Bruno, no sendmail.ini tem o código que eu postei lá em cima, em [sendmail]. vou tentar adicionar o hostname e segunda te aviso, pois nao estou no trabalho agora. muito obrigado

Comment: Bruno, acabei de fazer o teste, o sendmail.ini ficou assim:


    [sendmail]

    hostname=10.190.103.4:3128
    smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port=587
    error_logfile=error.log
    debug_logfile=debug.log
    smtp_ssl=auto
    auth_username=meuemail@gmail.com
    auth_password=senha
    smtp_ssl=tls
    tls_certcheck off

Não funcionou.

Comment: Tentei tb no php.ini

Tentei tb no php.ini

[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = meuemail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\"\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = Off
hostname=10.190.103.4:3128


Nao funcionou.

Comment: Esse path do sendmail no PHP.INI tá com aspas a mais. Deveria ser `sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\ -t"`. Caso não resolva, edite a resposta e adicione o conteúdo dos arquivos de log.